# Using Discord.js to get all of the messages sent since the bot went offline

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am making a bot that will store all of the messages sent in a channel into a txt file on my computer. Since I don't have my computer on all the time and I run the bot on my computer it leaves gaps in messages stored in the .txt file. I am trying to make it so that my bot will get all the messages sent since it went offline and store all of them in my file. I created a txt file that saves the message id of every message, it will overwrite the last message so its basically just a file with one message id in it. When my bot starts a boolean variable is instantiated to false and will be set to true once the startup procedure has been completed. This is what I have so far:

```
var latest;
var beenRunning = false;

bot.on('message', msg => {
    latest = msg.id;
    if(beenRunning == false) {
      msg.channel.messages.fetch(latest, {limit: 100})
      .then(messages =>  
        //code to get messages since last online
        )
      .catch(console.error);
      beenRunning = true;
    }
    else {
      messageTest(msg);
    }
    fs.writeFile('lastMsg.txt', latest, (err) => { 
      if (err) throw err; 
  }) 
});
```

I am not sure how to get every message since going offline using the fetch() method. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are structuring your lastMsg.txt, so I just used json.

Might be a bit slow since it'll be a bigger file and its using a lot of array higher functions

```js
let logged = require("./lastMsg.json");
let beenRunning;

bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (!beenRunning) {
        msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 })
            .then(messages => {
                const reduced = messages
                    .map(e => ({ id: e.id, content: e.content }))
                    .filter(e => {
                        return logged.find(l => l.id === e.id && l.content === e.content);
                    });

                logged = logged.concat(reduced.array());
                beenRunning = true;
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    } else {
        messageTest(msg);
    }

    fs.writeFile('lastMsg.json', JSON.stringify(logged), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    })
});
```

Initalize your `./lastMsg.json` to
`[]`